# How to get Authorization information from ASP.NET MVC cshtml and set it to Headers["Authorization"] of jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

How to get Authorization from ASP.net MVC cshtml and set it to Headers["Authorization"] of jquery ajax.

I success login to ASP.NET MVC and use FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Name, model.RememberMe), in webpage Request.IsAuthenticated & User.Identity.Name display correctly.

On WEB API Odata of my webapplication, i use AuthorizeAttribute class to make only Authorize user to access.
Here is my Global

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ...
            WebApiOdataConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new MembershipHttpAuthorizeAttribute());
            ... 
        }
```

Here is my MembershipHttpAuthorizeAttribute

```
public class MembershipHttpAuthorizeAttribute : BasicHttpAuthorizeAttribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Implement to include authentication logic and create IPrincipal
        /// </summary>
        protected override bool TryCreatePrincipal(string user, string password,
            out IPrincipal principal)
        {
            principal = null;
            if (!Membership.Provider.ValidateUser(user, password))
                return false;
            //FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user, true);
            string[] roles = System.Web.Security.Roles.Provider.GetRolesForUser(user);
            principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(user), roles);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Here is my BasicHttpAuthorizeAttribute

```
public abstract class BasicHttpAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private const string BasicAuthResponseHeader = "WWW-Authenticate";
        private const string BasicAuthResponseHeaderValue = "Basic";


        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext == null)
                throw Error.ArgumentNull("actionContext");
            if (AuthorizationDisabled(actionContext)
                || AuthorizeRequest(actionContext.ControllerContext.Request))
                return;
            this.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext == null)
                throw Error.ArgumentNull("actionContext");
            actionContext.Response = CreateUnauthorizedResponse(actionContext
                .ControllerContext.Request);
        }

        private HttpResponseMessage CreateUnauthorizedResponse(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            var result = new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
                RequestMessage = request
            };

            //we need to include WWW-Authenticate header in our response,
            //so our client knows we are using HTTP authentication
            result.Headers.Add(BasicAuthResponseHeader, BasicAuthResponseHeaderValue);
            return result;
        }

        private static bool AuthorizationDisabled(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            //support new AllowAnonymousAttribute
            if (!actionContext.ActionDescriptor
                .GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any())
                return actionContext.ControllerContext
                    .ControllerDescriptor
                    .GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any();
            else
                return true;
        }

        private bool AuthorizeRequest(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            AuthenticationHeaderValue authValue = request.Headers.Authorization;
            if (authValue == null || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authValue.Parameter)
                || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authValue.Scheme)
                || authValue.Scheme != BasicAuthResponseHeaderValue)
            {
                return false;
            }

            string[] parsedHeader = ParseAuthorizationHeader(authValue.Parameter);
            if (parsedHeader == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            IPrincipal principal = null;
            if (TryCreatePrincipal(parsedHeader[0], parsedHeader[1], out principal))
            {
                HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
                return CheckRoles(principal) && CheckUsers(principal);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private bool CheckUsers(IPrincipal principal)
        {
            string[] users = UsersSplit;
            if (users.Length == 0) return true;
            //NOTE: This is a case sensitive comparison
            return users.Any(u => principal.Identity.Name == u);
        }

        private bool CheckRoles(IPrincipal principal)
        {
            string[] roles = RolesSplit;
            if (roles.Length == 0) return true;
            return roles.Any(principal.IsInRole);
        }

        private string[] ParseAuthorizationHeader(string authHeader)
        {
            string[] credentials = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert
                                                            .FromBase64String(authHeader))
                                                            .Split(
                                                            new[] { ':' });
            if (credentials.Length != 2 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials[0])
                || string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials[1])) return null;
            return credentials;
        }

        protected string[] RolesSplit
        {
            get { return SplitStrings(Roles); }
        }

        protected string[] UsersSplit
        {
            get { return SplitStrings(Users); }
        }

        protected static string[] SplitStrings(string input)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input)) return new string[0];
        var result = input.Split(',')
            .Where(s=>!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.Trim()));
        return result.Select(s =>s.Trim()).ToArray();
    }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implement to include authentication logic and create IPrincipal
        /// </summary>
        protected abstract bool TryCreatePrincipal(string user, string password,
            out IPrincipal principal);
    }
```

On jquery ajax

```
...
 ajax: {
                        beforeSend: function (jqXhr, settings) {
                            jqXhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", ????); //I want set value of my current login  here
                        }
                    },
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed BasicHttpAuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization to

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext == null)
                throw Error.ArgumentNull("actionContext");

            if (AuthorizationDisabled(actionContext))
                return;

            //Case that user is authenticated using forms authentication
            //so no need to check header for basic authentication.
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) //If current user is authenticated 
            {
                var principal = HttpContext.Current.User;
                if(CheckRoles(principal) && CheckUsers(principal))
                    return;
            }
            else if (AuthorizeRequest(actionContext.ControllerContext.Request)) //Use Basic Auth information
                return;

            this.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
        }
```

and it work